# How to pass a variable from one python script to an other one?

Tags: python, json, python-2.x

I have 2 scripts and at the end of the first a want to pass data to the second script: Here's my code, this is what I tried but I can't get anything:

## user.py

```py
import subprocess

command = "python C:\Users\...\credentials.py"
JSON = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
print JSON
```

## credentials.py (relatively simple)

```py
# bla bla bla
return JSON_credentials
```

It returns nothing and I want to know if there is a way to do what I need to do (obvious ahah)

Thanks for your help
!

Comment: credentials.py should _print_ the credentials instead of _returning_ them.  (However, your code can't be as shown, because you can't `return` from top-level code; it must be inside of a function, so you would have to show us the real code.)

Comment: And can I get the print after that ?

Comment: user.py is checking the _output_ of credentials.py, so yes, print is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `check_output` method captures output from stdout. `return` does not write anything to stdout. That keyword is used to pass data within a single Python program.

Try something like:

```
import sys
# bla bla bla
sys.stdout.write(JSON_credentials)
```

Or simply:

```
# bla bla bla
print JSON_credentials
```

Comment: I don't really want to print them, I want to pass the JSON array without showing anything in the CLI, thanks for yout help

Comment: Have you tried the above code? It will get the data you need. It will be much more challenging to do this without printing anything to stdout. Processes cannot communicate any other way.

Comment: Oh okay it is not showing the print on the CLI, I tought it will. Thank you very much for your help !